# Anypoint DevKit plugin in Anypoint Studio installation issue

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

Installing Anypoint DevKit Extension in Anypoint studio which is installed as Eclipse [Plugin](http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/addons/). In install remediaton page, checked the option "update my installation to be compatible with the items being installed" and then proceed installation.

During installation I receive the error ,

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed  session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=).  No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.mule.tooling.ui.contribution.sfdc.3.5.0,6.2.3.201507231244
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.mule.tooling.ui.contribution.sqs.3.5.0,3.1.0.201507241546
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.mule.tooling.ui.extension.sfdc.3.5.0,6.2.3.201507231244
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.mule.tooling.ui.extension.sqs.3.5.0,3.1.0.201507241546

How to solve this?

Comment: Thanks, it worked after upgrading to any point studio 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to **update** your current IDE to make it work... I can find the solution here in your link you posted:- http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/cannot-install-anypoint-dev-kit-in-anypoint-studio-eclipse-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think it requires MAVEN configuration before installing DevKit.

Answer (score 0):

while downloading and installing the devkit you should be connected to internet. Which will download features from above given repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You can download plug-in as install offline or install using direct internet instead of inside any proxy.

Comment: Can you provide more direction of how to do this within Eclipse or link to a web resource?

Comment: Please follow step given in Mulesoft doc. It is well explain.     https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.7/